# How to pass data to Prawn using a proc

Tags: ruby, proc, prawn

I am trying to have a repo with my Prawn templates and another one which is going to create the Prawn pdfs.

Imagine something like this:

```
# Repo A
require 'template_from_repo_b'
p = get_my_proc  # from repo b
Prawn::Document.new(&p).render

# Repo B
def get_my_proc
  proc do
    text 'hello world'
  end 
end
```

And it works. But how can I pass data to that proc. Is that possible?

I wonder if there is a way to load code into a variable like in PHP.

```
# File to include
<?php
return 'abc';

# Usage
$abc = include 'include.php';
```

So I could load the proc directly to a variable. I want to be able to simplify as possible the proc templates.

Thank you!

Comment: `new` doesn't take a proc, though; `generate` might since it takes a block.

Comment: It does. I just tried again. However I was missing the & before the proc on Document.new(&p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution. It feels a little weird so I am not sure if I am going to use it. Any suggestion will be appreciated, I am not a ruby pro.

```
require 'prawn'

def make_proc(data)
  proc do
    text data[:greet]
  end
end

data = { greet: 'Hello World' }
p = make_proc data
bytes = Prawn::Document.new(&p).render
open('test.pdf', 'wb') { |f| f.puts bytes }
```

Comment: Nothing weird about it; that's how you pass a proc as an implicit block.